# Copying selected nodes and children with XLST

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having trouble with an XSLT transformation and I'm hoping someone could help me out. 
Here is the structure of the data I am working with,

```
<excelFiles>
    <sheet>
        <row index='1'>
            <column_1>allowedValue</column_1>
            <column_2>US</column_2>
             <column_3>allowedValue</column_3>
        </row>
        <row index='1'>
           <column_1>notAllowedValue</column_1>
           <column_2>US</column_2>
           <column_3>allowedValue</column_3>
        </row>
  </sheet>
</excelFiles>
```

What I am trying to do is only copy rows where none of the child nodes contain invalid data. Would this be possible with XSLT? I am constrained to only use XSLTto solve this issue.

Edit for clarity: The invalid data is when the only value in the node is the '-' character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with an identity transformation and then add a no-op template that matches the nodes you *don't* want and ignores them:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!-- ignore any row element that has any child element whose text value is
       a single hyphen -->
  <xsl:template match="row[* = '-']" />

  <!-- copy everything else -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That works perfectly exactly what I was looking for, my main issue was having my match template after the copy. Thanks a lot.